# Error to return result from Action via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a devexpress grid in my view and a submit button wich executes a action to export the data. 
If i do this way it execute the action and returns me the download file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export","Product"))
{
   <input type="submit" value="export"/>
}
```

But if i do the submit like this:

```
function OnCommandExecuted(s, e) {
    if (e.item.name == "SendData") {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/Export'
        });
    }
}
```

The js calls and executes the action normally, but it not returns the download.

The code of my Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Export()
    {
       return GridViewExtension.ExportToXls(CreateExportGridViewSettings(),  Session["product"] as List<Product>);
    }
```

I put a breakpoint in the action and the javascript code is calling the action normally, but it not return the download (without any errors).
What im missing here?

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't be using AJAX to download files. But still if you want to use JQuery AJAX to make files download, then you can use window.open() in JQuery and open File Resource URL in that which will trigger download.

Let the Action return Json data holding URL to the file resource -

```
    public ActionResult Download(string fileId)
    {
        return new JsonResult(){ Data = "File URL to Download using fileId, probably with some querystrings", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

Then in your JQuery -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Download")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ fileId: "123"}),
            success: function (data) {
                window.open(data, "_blank");
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

Then when you click button, a URL pointing to the File will be returned to JQuery from Action method. Then JQuery opens that URL in a new Window and make file download.

Alternatively you can also try plugins like [JQuery FileDownload](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) which delivers AJAX experience in downloading files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im using a devexpress ribbon component, and the custom devexpress buttons inside this ribbon only allows me call an action via script. thats why im using it.